# Using izip over second dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, izip

I have the following:

```
for i in xrange(n):
    label = labels[i]
    frame = data[:, i]
    dostuff()
```

Where data is a 2-D `numpy` array.  I'd like to rewrite it using `izip`.

```
for label, frame in izip(labels, ???):
    dostuff()
```

What do I replace `???` with to get this to work?

Comment: What is dostuff(), namely can it be implemented in numpy ufuncs

Comment: @vincent, no the dostuff() can't be done in numpy unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use `izip()`, you can do it like this:

```
for label, frame in izip(labels, data.T):
    dostuff()
```

It is generally advisable not to iterate over a NumPy array using a Python loop, but rather use [NumPy ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) to do the loops in C code.  How to do this, depends on what `dostuff()` actually does.

Comment: Does the data.T operation create a new array (a slow operation) or does it just change how you access the data?  My data array is really large.

Comment: @Jeff: `data.T` will create a new array object sharing the same data as `data`.  Your data won't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
  ??? = numpy.transpose(data)
```

EDIT: remove second version. Since transpose doesn't copy the array like I assumed there is no reason to anything as crazy as I was doing.

Comment: More than one `Ellipsis` object in slicing a NumPy array won't yield the expected result -- the first one will consume all remaining dimensions.  You probably meant `slice(None)` instead, but even then the function `iterate_axis()` will be slower than using NumPy directly.

Comment: @Sven Marnach, I'm using the Ellipsis for the unexpected result because I wasn't sure how to produce a : slice. I'm guessing that is what slice(None) represents?

Comment: Yes, `data[slice(None)]` is equivalent to `data[:]`.

Comment: @Sven Marnach, thanks. I've never need it before, but now I know how to do it!